# Pinterest error invalid sdk client key ios

Tags: ios, pinterest

I am implementing Pinterest in my app.My code is as follows:

```
pinterest = [[Pinterest alloc]initWithClientId:@"Myapp_ClientID"]; 
NSURL *imageURL     = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://7-themes.com"]; 
NSURL *sourceURL    = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://7-themes.com/data_images/out/42/6914793-tropical-beach-images.jpg"];

[pinterest createPinWithImageURL:sourceURL
                       sourceURL:sourceURL
                     description:@"Pinning from Pin It Demo"];
```

I registered app and got client id which I put in my code but when run on device it always give me error invalid client id

Answer (score 0):

You are giving the Client key wrong. (Which should be obvious). Most likely this question will be taken off but let me help you anyways:

```
pinterest = [[Pinterest alloc]initWithClientId:@"Myapp_ClientID"];
```

On the above line you are giving the client key wrong. Sdk client keys are long and with alternating Alpha numeric characters to enhance security. What you are doing is, you are passing it a string which holds the value Myapp_ClientID. So your operation is aborted.

If you have declared `Myapp_ClientID` as a constant or it is a variable of corresponding type, then simply use this line:

```
pinterest = [[Pinterest alloc]initWithClientId:Myapp_ClientID];
```

Else provide the correct client key like:

```
pinterest = [[Pinterest alloc]initWithClientId:@"Your client key here"];
```

Comment: Thanks @NSNoob I gave proper clientId, It's just an example how I am giving same as you showed above like pinterest = [[Pinterest alloc]initWithClientId:Myapp_ClientID]; but still giving error, I don't why? can you plese help me out?

Comment: @AshokKumar What is the value in the variable/constant `Myapp_ClientID`? In the code that you provided you are clearly not giving it like I am giving it.

Comment: Is this correct as the one provided to you by Pinterest? Also delete your comment, it might jeopardize security of your app

Comment: Yes ofcourse it is correct. I don't why it's heppening can you give any idea about it?

Comment: It is really hard to deduce what went wrong as it is a broad subject. Refer to https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/sdks/ios/ to compare and see where you went wrong.